# Block photos of snakes in browser

Tags: web-filtering

Is there any way to try to block photos of snakes in a browser, similar to how one might block adult content or advertisements?

We've got a person who is learning Python but is very disturbed by photos of snakes and very often when doing searches on Python or Anaconda lots of photos of snakes are returned.

Comment: Do you want to block pictures on the Browser or on the Search Engine? If it's on Google, you can switch to a search engine that doesn't display images on the front page.

Comment: @Don'tRoothereplz... That is an idea (about switching search engines) though it would be even better if it were possible to filter them on all pages, since a lot of Python language sites have photos of python snakes

Comment: why search for anaconda??

Comment: @SargeBorsch Anaconda is a scientific Python suite by Continuum, Inc

Answer (score 1):

This is rather a crude and conditional way of doing this.

You can download an extension to block all images and then switch it on. Unfortunately this blocks all images but will serve your cause.

For Chrome : [Hide Images](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-images/npkjfnpmjehafgklcnnphlegdbbafafg?hl=en-GB)

For Firefox : [Image Block](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-block/)